# raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to fix my error but it's not working for me. My application it was working perfectly until I generate devise user. No one of the solutions on stackoverflow worked it. Thanks.

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Comment: Can you paste the devise generated migration file?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `email` is already present in the users table, you need to remove the following line from devise generated migration file

```
t.string :email
```

More info here

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns

Comment: If your app isn't on  production yet, you can drop the db, remove the earlier migration for `users` table and then rerun  `rails db:migrate`